# Localizing storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, storyboard

When I click on localizing a storyboard I usullay get a .strings file, but in a pod I only get the option to create a whole new storyboard for localization:

Before localizing:

[image: Before localizing]

After localizing:

[image: After localizing]

How can I get a strings file instead of new storyboards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the problem. It seems that you only get that option if you have a base Internationalization. Which means that the "Use Base Internationalization" checkbox in the Project's Info tab has to be checked:

[image]